# Is there a way to enable FIPS Mode (for FIPS 140 compliance) while debugging an application?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, fips

I have the unfortunate happenstance of developing a C# application that must run under FIPS mode in production.

I'm trying to test if it will work under FIPS mode, but I am finding that this causes *severe* and systematic problems for Visual Studio. I keep getting errors during the build (even though my application builds fine outside of Visual Studio), even though I've added the [`<enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false" />`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202806(v=vs.110).aspx) setting to both MSBuild's and Visual Studio's configuration files.

I'd really rather not have to hunt down every possible .NET build tool that could blow up with this setting globally enabled, so is there a way to do it the other way around? Can I turn it *on* while my application runs to make sure it won't blow up my app?

I did try `<enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="true" />`, but as documented, it only enables FIPS Mode if the global setting is enabled.